# jQuery Mobile loses styles and more upon refresh of page

Tags: jquery-mobile

This is my first jQuery mobile project I am stuck on this one problem. This is for a criminal records research,  and works well but if the user refreshes the page all types of problems start to happen.. the styles are gone and the the jquery actions no longer work after page refresh

If you goto http://mobile.datadoesit.com/select_search.php?firstname=john&lastname=mason&button=Search

and click on Criminal, you will see it pulls the records and all works as it should

now on the results page, if you refresh (F5) all styles are gone

Does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed because as soon as you've fixed the problem the question becomes useless for anyone having the same problem later. For further information see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: this is why I also explained the problem, thanks for the response though it really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what did you think will happen when **results_criminal.php** doesn't have jQuery Mobile CSS/JS included in the HEAD?

Comment: yes it is in the head, it would not work at all if not -- again when the user clicks "Search", and is taken to the result_criminal.php page, it works fine and all styles and actions work -- but if the hit refresh then the css is gone and actions do not work